# what's mean of npm scripts two dahses?

Tags: node.js, npm, scripting

These scripts have two dashes expression. (e.g. server:dev -- --inline --hot)

```
"server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
"server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
"server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
"server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
"server": "npm run server:dev",
"start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run server:dev\" \"nodemon --watch server server-start.js\" ",
```

What is the meaning of these two dashes?
And what's the name of this expression?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash

Comment: Thank you for nice advice!!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a way to pass arguments to npm-run-script.

```
npm run <command> [-- <args>]
```

From the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script):

As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option -- is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script:

```
npm run test -- --grep="pattern"
```