# npm run: how to pass parameter and replace placeholder by param in script call

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I want to to define a `scripts` entry in my package.json to simplify building for several environments.

In the script execution I need to replace `$1` (or whatever syntax I need for a placeholder) by a parameter I would pass to `npm run build-script` like for example `--env=prod` or even simpler, `--prod`. How can I do that? Other questions and answers I found here didn't help me solve the problem.

```json
"scripts": { 
  "build-for": "ng build --output-path=../../web/admin-v2 --env=$1 --base-href=\"/admin-v2/\""
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for double dash https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743871/205696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often resort to creating a utility node script for this kind of scenario and invoke it via the `scripts` section of `package.json`.

---

**build-for.js**

```js
var nodeCLI = require('shelljs-nodecli');

var env = '--env=foo'; // <-- Default env flag/value when no arg provided.

if (process.argv.indexOf('--prod') !== -1) {
  env = '--env=prod';
}

// Check for other possible env values
if (process.argv.indexOf('--quux') !== -1) {
  env = '--env=quux';
}

// Run the ng build command
nodeCLI.exec('ng', 'build', '--output-path=../../web/admin-v2', env, '--base-href=\"/admin-v2/\"');
```

`build-for.js` utilizes nodes [process.argv](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to ascertain the argument/flag passed via the CLI and then invokes the `ng` command *(the one currently defined in your `package.json`)* using [shelljs-nodecli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs-nodecli).

`npm i -D shelljs-nodecli`

Lets assume that `build-for.js` is saved to a hidden folder named `.scripts` in your projects root directory; then your `scripts` section of `package.json` will be defined as follows:

**package.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build-for": "node ./.scripts/build-for"
  },
  ...
}
```

---

**Running the script**

Invoke the npm script by running:

`npm run build-for -- --prod`

Note the special `--` before the argument `--prod` must be included as explained [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script)

> *As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option -- is used by getopt to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to your script:*

Given the logic curently in the `build-for.js` - when no arguments are passed, for example:

`npm run build-for`

...the `env` flag will be set to `--env=foo`

Running the following:

`npm run build-for -- --quux`

...will result in the `env` flag will be set to `--env=quux`

---

**Caveat**

I haven't fully tested `build-for.js`, so you may find that you don't need to escape the double-quotes in this part `'--base-href=\"/admin-v2/\"'` of the following command *(`nodeCLI` may handle that for you.)*:

```js
// Run the ng build command
nodeCLI.exec('ng', 'build', '--output-path=../../web/admin-v2', env, '--base-href=\"/admin-v2/\"');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, will try that out. It feels a little disappointing that npm seemingly doesn't have a standard mechanism for this quite common need.

Comment: My pleasure _connexo_. I feel your disappointment too. I believe this feature has been requested many times as per e.g. [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518#issuecomment-46791134). However, the pertinent part is the project owners [reply](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518#issuecomment-46915480). It states: _"We are not going to support passing args into the middle of the script, sorry."_. Hence the workaround provided in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you're looking for but you can use environment variables & provide them inline:

package.json script:
`"<script>": "echo ${ENV1} ${ENV2}"`

run like so:
`ENV1=a ENV2=b npm run <script>`

```
$ npm run <script>
a b
```