# Setting AWS credentials in serverless framework when it is installed as a dev dependency

Tags: node.js, npm, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I have installed the serverless framework as a dev dependency using:

```js
npm -i --save-dev serverless
```

I have also set `sls:sls` in the `scripts` in `package.json`

Now sls works, meaning that I can run it by typing "npm run sls". I want to set my AWS credentials so by writing.

```
npm run sls config credentials --provider aws, --key XXXXXX, --secret XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

but it does not work, could you please help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters can be passed to run-script commands using `--`

You can try
`npm run sls -- config credentials --provider aws, --key XXXXXX, --secret XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

For more details checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44743871/5798816

Comment: This works, just the comas are extra and should be eliminated.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this is to set the AWS environment variables used by the AWS CLI and AWS SDK since the serverless framework uses the AWS SDK under the hood. More information can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html).
The process that I did was:

1. Set the credentials in an AWS user profile. For example, let's call it `star`.
2. Open the terminal and type `export AWS_PROFILE=star`
3. Then in the terminal go to the folder when you have installed serverless framework as a dependency and type `npm run sls deploy` to deploy your changes to aws or some other clould.